# Check on the status code of url before redirect_to in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, redirect, http-status-codes

I have action `check_status` in `instances_controller`, and I want to check on status code of URL before redirect_to it.

if `status_code` is 200 redirect_to it, else go to view page.

This is the pseudo-code of `check_status` action:

```
def check_status
  if "http://www.web.com".status_code == 200
    redirect_to "http://www.web.com"
  else
    #DO Nothing, and go to its view
  end
end
```

For example `get '/about' => 'instances#check_status'`, and i want to check if (web.com) get `status=200` visit (web.com)

Comment: Can u explain use case? It will make question clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this - but beware:

1. Your user will have to wait for your response check to complete before they get redirected. If you're checking a slow server, that could be up to 30 seconds before they get sent somewhere else.
2. There's no guarantee that the user will get the same result you got when you checked.

Here's some code that uses [Ruby's `Net::HTTP` module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to perform that web request:

```
require 'net/http'

def check_status(url)
  uri = URI(url)
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Head.new uri.request_uri
    response = http.request request

    if response == Net::HTTPSuccess
      redirect_to url and return
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure you're passing in full URLs to this method, complete with an `http://` or `https://` prefix, or this won't work.

If you were worried about that performance hit, you could cache the results for a short while and check those before returning. That is, when you look up a URL you can save the time of the lookup & the status code retrieved. Then, on the next lookup, if you've checked that domain in the past 24 hours, return the redirect immediately rather than checking it again.

Comment: I got this error from your code (undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x00000002f96e90 URL:www.google.com>)

Comment: That error's from your data, not from my code. :) If you don't specify a protocol, the `uri` module constructs a generic URI. You need an HTTP URI. That is, `URI('www.google.com')` returns a `URI::Generic`object (which has no `request_uri` method). `URI('http://www.google.com/')` returns a `URI::HTTP` object, which works fine. I'll add a note to my original answer to flag this.

Answer (score 0):

For me just this one is working to check the response

The `==` one gets no match...

```
response.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
```

Comment: Its also written like this in the docs. So maybe edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Alex's answer, you can use `curl` tool instead of `Net::HTTP` module.

`system('curl www.google.com') # => true`

`system('curl www.google_not_valid.com') # => false`

Comment: system('curl www.google_not_valid.com') returns true